# C++ methods with same name but different params

Tags: c++

Why in C++ it was done so that the compiler "forgets" about other methods with the same name but different parameters if you overrides one of such methods?

```
struct A {
  void virtual f() {}
  void virtual f(int) {}
  void testA() {f(); f(1);} // OK
 };

struct B :  public A {
  void f() override {}
  void testB() {f(); f(1);} // Error
};
```

It seems that this is pointless behavior ... no?

Comment: How would you say you didn't want one of them to be called when using a child class if it wasn't appropriate if the language didn't do this?  It seems much safer to enumerate the methods you do want to be allowed to be used.

Comment: Are you asking why the language specifies this? Because the answer to why the compiler does it is "because the language spec says it should do so".

Comment: @juanchopanza I'm guessing the question is "why did the designers of the language choose this over looking at every function with the same name in the entire class hierarchy".

Comment: "guess" was used colloquially.  You're being pedantic, it's obvious the question isn't "why didn't he compiler writers ignore the spec and make the compiler behave some other way".

Comment: @xaxxon No, I am asking OP to clarify the question. If you think I'm being pedantic, read the only answer, which basically says "because the language says so".

Comment: @juanchopanza It's unlikely someone with this level of understanding of C++ is going to be able to even comprehend the concept of c++ compilers not actually being the spec.   The clarification you're asking for is like a 5 year old asking what 17+18 is and you asking "well, that depends on what base you're working in"  They're just going to look at you funny when they simply want you to tell them "35".

Comment: @xaxxon There are things a spec can leave unspecified and up to the implementation. There are other things that may be left undefined. And there are compilers that don't follow certain parts of the spec. On top of that, often (most times in my experience) posters are happy to be shown the relevant parts of the spec, i.e. they aren't really interested in the *why* part. Now if you read the answers, you'll see the question isn't that clear after all.

Comment: This isn't a special behaviour of members in C++; all scoping works like this. A name in an inner scope hides the same name in the outer scope.

Comment: Comments like "because spec is so" are nice. This is a question about real understanding C++ ... about reasons of specifying something. I mean the situations which will give bad things if not restrict something in specification.

Comment: I was asking about examples of situations which will give bad things if there will be no restrictions of something in specification. Let's be smart and exact, and do not write obvious ideas or smooth clouds of words like "The clarification you're asking for is like a 5 year old asking what 17+18". Thanks!

Comment: xaxxon: "How would you say you didn't want one of them to be called when using a child class if it wasn't appropriate if the language didn't do this"
Did not get why existing methods of restriction of usage of C++ are not appropriate here?

Comment: If names in an inner scope did not hide names in an outer scope, you could add a function with the same name in one scope and change the behaviour of code in another; which is bad.

Comment: @Simple Where do you see the question about inner-outer scopes? Did not get your idea.

Comment: A class body is a scope. The base class is the outer scope and the derived class is the inner scope. I'm just saying this isn't special behaviour WRT classes. All scopes behave like this.

Comment: Inheritance is not scoping. Virtual methods is just to influence to the things which are done by parent with the code in the child. Could new commenters please write an answer ... not a comment, please. Too many comments are under question by now.

Comment: Inheritance is scoping. But whatever. I'm not going to argue my point anymore.

Comment: @Simple You are right ... let's be exact ... could you please share a link where it is said that C++ thinks about inheritance the same as about scoping.
Moreover my main question is about "inner scope" in these terms. It is about how things are working inside class B. No questions about influence of B on A (inner scope to outer scope as it is expressed in your idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you could add a using-statement to make all the A::f methods visible, something similar to this:

```
  struct B :  public A {
    using A::f;
    void f() override {}
    void testB() {f(); f(1);} // No Error
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing ... this seems better than overriding all f(...) with obvious implementation (which call each f(...) analogue of parent class).

Comment: I did not accept your answer since the question is about reasons of hiding methods with same name. But your answer is of real help if one do not want to hide.

Answer (score 1):

When you override a member function in a child-class, you *hide* the name of the parent class, it's just how the language works. If you want to use a function from the parent class you have to be explicit, like e.g. `A::f(1)`.

Comment: If you are explicit in calling virtual method you are killing the whole idea of methods visualization. If you did not get my point please say so I will be more specific/detailed.

Comment: @Progrev That is how overriding and hiding works, it really *hides* the parents symbols. Either use explicit scoping or do like suggested by Jojje with the `using` keyword. Either way there is something explicit you need to do.

Comment: "That is how overriding and hiding works"
This is "specs say so" answer. And I asked the reason of it
"Either use explicit scoping or ..." explicit scoping "kills" vitalization! need examples or you get it? Jojje's idea is good. I wrote him my thanks!

Comment: @Progrev If you like Jojje's answer and it does what you want, why not vote for it? Or even accept it?

Comment: Tried 2 times. Unable to vote. Did no accept because the question is about the reasons of hiding other members with same name. So I can only give him my thanks.
By the way ... you can vote for him if you get why your way is not working ;)